# How to pass multiple objects to laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

```
$stores = $store->where('vendor_id', '=', $id)->get(); 
$products = Product::where('store_id', '=', $stores->id)->get();
```

`$stores` has multiple objects how can I pass multiple objects to another query as shown below. Need to match all `id` returned from `Store` model. Using `first()` returns only one object but in this case need to get `all` the stores and products related to those stores.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereIn()` for that purpose. Using your example as base:

```
$stores = $store::where('vendor_id', $id)->lists('id');
$products = Product::whereIn('store_id', $stores)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this where `$id` is a given parameter or variable:

```
$stores_id = Store::all()->where('vendor_id', $id)->lists('id');
$products = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $stores_id)->get();
```

This is assuming that you're using the default table names for the different models, that is `products` table name for the `Product` model.

The method `lists($column_name)` will return an array with the elements of the given column. The `whereIn($array)` clause acts like the `ÌN` clause in SQL.

NOTE: when using `where` you don't have to put the `=` sign, as Laravel will interpret it if you leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your model relationship, you could do this.

```
$stores = $store -> with('products') -> where('vendor_id',$id) ->first();
```

The query will fetch all products for the selected store.